# Reading a JSON file uses a lot of memory in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a bit surprised that reading a 274.9MB `json` file and storing it on a variable as an array of objects causes a 1.1GB usage of Resident Set Size memory in node.js.

How can this be? it seems a bit excessive.

```
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises'

const raw = await readFile('big.json', 'utf8')
const file = JSON.parse(raw)

console.log('Length: ', file.length)
console.log(
  `Memory: ${Math.round((process.memoryUsage().rss / 1024 / 1024) * 100) / 100} MB`
)
```

```
Length: 920885
Memory: 1193.05 MB
```

Here are the contents of one object as an example

```js
{
  keyword: '1 hour circuit training',
  url: 'https://www.pinterest.com/pin/457467274629879495',
  rank: 1,
  page: 1,
  type: 'inline_images',
  title: 'image result',
  domain: '-',
  sitelinks: false
}
....
```

Comment: What's the content of the file? It's probably a big difference if it's an array with 920'885 numbers or 920'885 booleans

Comment: What's the data for? Do you really need *that* much data *each run*? ..and reading it from file each time? Have you considered parsing the file once and then store the results in database, cache or something? (I know this doesn't answer the question, I'm just inescapably curious about such an extreme use case. What is the reponse time?)

Comment: Can the data be consolidated into "a few"(fewer?) items? Or does it have to be all individual data items stored in the file?

Comment: Not that massive here is an example `1 hour circuit training https://www.pinterest.com/pin/457467274629879495/ 2 1 inline_images Image result for 1 hour circuit training - FALSE`

Comment: Are you storing image data in the file? Would it be an option to process the file once and move the image data to their respective files? (I probably wouldn't focus on the memory usage right now, at least, but instead try to bring the size of the file down. My 2 cents..)

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo, no, just strings, numbers and booleans

Comment: Ah, got it. Well, then I too would say it's a reasonable memory usage. There are data structures behind the scene that take up memory for each item in addition to the raw data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about the expected size. At least half a gig is being taken up by the string content of big.json - JavaScript uses UCS-2, so each character must necessarily take 2 bytes. Note you're not freeing it (no `delete` statement), so it's still referred-to from the stack when you take the measurement.
Hard to tell exactly what the memory layout of an "array of objects" is, but objects, being hash maps, do have some overhead. If they contain strings, then again, count each character double.
All in all, this memory usage is realistic and not entirely unexpected.